# How to rewrite C++ template code for Borland compiler

Tags: c++, c++builder, mysql++

I'm trying to compile MySql++ using Borland's 32-bit compiler. This compiler is well known to have problems with some template syntax. The compiler is also almost obsolete, as it is being replaced with the clang compiler.

However, if the following code can be fixed into a compilable version, time would be saved.

The compiler error occurs at the following line:

```
template <> MYSQLPP_EXPORT bool String::conv(bool) const;
```

The compiler error is:

> [bcc32 Error] mystring.h(726): E2506 Explicit specialization of 'String::conv<Type>(Type) const' is ambiguous: must specify template arguments
>      Full parser context
>      transaction.cpp(32): #include lib\query.h
>      query.h(37): #include lib\result.h
>      result.h(40): #include lib\row.h
>      row.h(33): #include lib\mystring.h
>      mystring.h(46): namespace mysqlpp

`String` is a custom string class, and the `conv()` function is an inline template function within the `String` class:

```
/// \brief Template for converting the column data to most any
/// numeric data type.
template <class Type>
Type conv(Type) const
{
    // Conversions are done using one of double/long/ulong/llong/ullong
    // so we call a helper function to do the work using that type.
    // This reduces the amount of template code instantiated.
    typedef typename detail::conv_promotion<Type>::type conv_type;
    return do_conv<conv_type>(typeid(Type).name());
}
```

I've tried various modifications, but with no success.

Comment: Have you tried those suggestions?: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/compile_errambigtspec_xml.html

Comment: Does `template <> MYSQLPP_EXPORT bool String::conv<bool>(bool) const;` work?

Comment: Thanks NathanOliver. That worked perfectly! How can I make your comment the correct answer?

Comment: mike, I was looking at that embarcadero help. I was confused it only giving half the answer, that is saying foo<int> instead of full answer, foo<int>(int). Not obvious to me.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson: "*How can I make your comment the correct answer?*" - you cannot.  Either you or Nathan will have to post a separate answer (yes, you can post your own answers to your own questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was given by nathanoliver

```
 template <> MYSQLPP_EXPORT bool String::conv<bool>(bool) const;
```

This silence the bcc32 compiler...!